# Generics parameter extends another parameter on java method

Tags: java, generics

Sorry, maybe it is a silly question, but I can't find answer.

Two generics parameters on a method, could one extends another?

```
public class A {
}

public class B extends A {
}

public class C {
}

public class Foo {

    public static <R extends A> void f1 (A t, R r){
    }

    // T and R are generics parameter, R bounds on T
    public static <T, R extends T > void f2(T t, R r) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        C c = new C();

        Foo.f1(a, b); // no error
        Foo.f1(a, c); // compile error, it's ok

        Foo.f2(a, b); // no error
        Foo.f2(a, c); // no error !  why? 
   }
}
```

The last `f2` method call has no compile error, but I think `C` is not subclass of `A`, compile error should be arised. Any help?

Comment: Why do you think `T` is `A`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because type parameters in your code where you call the method are implicit and for example if java compiler infers `T` and `R` to `Object` it's fine, isn't it? But if you declare them explicit it raises an error:

```
 Foo.<A, C>f2(a, c); //error as you wished
 Foo.<Object, Object>f2(a, c); //no errors and it's ok, isn't it?
```